# How to remove undersized carriage bolt from headboard?

Tags: tool-selection

[image]Outfit that set up our bed years ago used wrong sized round-head carriage bolts to attach the headboard to the frame. Should have used 3/8" and used 1/4" instead. The bolts are also too short, so no way to hold either end to remove the nuts. Square shoulders of bolts simply spin in the frame, so have been unable to remove the nuts. No room to use hacksaw on either end without damaging the wood. I'm no carpenter and have only basic tools, so would sure appreciate any advice on this!

Thanks!
Doc

Not a good pic of the bolt head but best I could get without rearranging the bedroom! It does NOT have a screwdriver slot in the head, although it appears to in the photo. It does however show that the bolt does not extend beyond the nut, so impossible to grip it. The nut is loosened as far as it will go. I tried clamping a piece of wood across the bolt head, but bolt still turns. Seems like it is a lock-nut of some kind.
Thanks!
Doc

Comment: Can you put a picture up on imgur or something and link to it in the comments or body of the question? I'm having a hard time picturing exactly how everything fits together.

Comment: Hi, welcome StackExchange. Without a pic it's impossible for us to visualise this properly, but given where and how most headboards are attached there should be no hesitation in hacksawing off the head of the bolt if that'll get you to where you need to be. I know it feels wrong to set out to damage the bed but after all nobody will be seeing the wood there normally, right? If you can't bring yourself to do this then drilling out the bolt head might work, but the required tools may be an issue plus if the bolt begins to turn you're probably stuffed (although there are some tricks you can try).

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate, Imgur *or something*? Duuude.

Comment: I'll try to get a pic this afternoon and post it. Hacksaw is out for now. Not enough room to get a hacksaw blade between the bolt head and frame. I doubt a small knife blade would even fit in there. Also not enough room at the nut end either. The nut is loose, but barely.

Comment: @Dave If you select the edit option below your question you can add an image by clicking the image option  in the 'Body' menu icons.

Comment: @Graphus -- too technical? I kid...

Comment: The hacksaw blade doesn't really need to *currently* have access behind the bolt head, you can create it using the sawing motion (hence the damage to the wood).....

Comment: Ah I see your Comment below, when you said "basic tools" I assumed no Dremel. Anyway since you have one + cutting disks your options open way up, from cutting a slot into the side of the nut (step 1 in creating a crude lock nut) but the simplest and most direct is slicing the nut in half so you can take it off, which will allow the bolt to just be knocked through the generously oversized hole it's going through. Won't take but 5 minutes per nut, and has the advantage that you don't really need access to the other side (although you are going to need at least some to fit the 3/8" replacements).

Comment: Make sure you check DIY SE and search previous Q&A about removing stuck fasteners.

Answer (score 1):

You could hacksaw a slot across the bolt and the rod that it's threaded onto. Use a slot screwdriver to hold the rod and a wrench to spin the nut.

Comment: That sounds like it might be exactly what I need!! Not sure I can get a hacksaw on it, but if not, maybe my little Dremel with a little cutting disk! Thanks, A.D.!!